# Standalone executable containing all dynamic libraries

Tags: windows, dll, shared-libraries, static-linking

I'm coding a tool supposed to run on windows. It links against so many shared libraries (DLLs) Qt library and so many MSYS/MinGW libs.

Is there a way to do following steps:

- Recursively find all libraries that final executable links against them
- Collect them (may be beside executable)
- Make a [huge?] standalone executable that all DLLs are embedded into it.

I'm familiar with [static linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library) concepts and [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) tool. Unfortunately there is no way to re-compile whole staff. Some libraries are purchased, closed-source tools and some other have legal issues with re-compiling.

Comment: What about non statically stubbed DLLs? Do these exist? Long time since I did work at this level so I can't recall if they did.

Comment: @PreetSangha I don't know!

Comment: Edit Found it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810279.aspx I think that basically puts the kibosh on this idea of recursively determining the DLLs statically. Unless you have a lot of time on your hands decompiling code.